# File upload chokes with 100-continue sometimes

Tags: python, linux, curl, flask, flask-restful

I call my web service using cURL to upload an image to a server. It works sometimes and at other times, it just haults at this point like shown below. The dehavior is very inconsistent - sometimes I manage to get the image uploaded and get a response, while at other times it would just sit there like shown below. What am I missing/doing wrong?

**Code Snippet:**

```
filename = str(id) + '.' + str(int(time.time())) + '.' +  secure_filename(file.filename)
filename_absolute = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], picture_type, filename)
file.save(filename_absolute)
```

**Sample Call [SUCCESS]:**

```
curl -v -F "id=1" -F 'file=@/tmp/2.png' -F 'picture_type=user' http://HOST:5000/api/v1/upload-picture
*   Trying 45.76.12.43...
* Connected to HOST (HOST) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/upload-picture HTTP/1.1
> Host: HOST:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 154309
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------7cc65a2371111afb
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 136
< Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.6
< Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 07:16:00 GMT
< 
{
  "data": {
    "link": "HOST:5000/api/v1/user/view-picture/1"
  }, 
  "error": 0, 
  "message": "File uploaded successfully"
* Closing connection 0
}
```

**Sample call [FAIL]:**

```
curl -v -F "id=1" -F 'file=@/tmp/2.png' -F 'picture_type=user' http://HOST:5000/api/v1/uplad-picture
*   Trying HOST...
* Connected to HOST (HOST) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/uplad-picture HTTP/1.1
> Host: HOST:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 154309
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------046a40f6e0480526
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
```

Comment: There's a really good article describing this ==> http://www.iandennismiller.com/posts/curl-http1-1-100-continue-and-multipartform-data-post.html.  Search for "conclusion" if you just want the nitty-gritty.

Comment: @Carlos thanks! That's a very interesting article. I am however, still not sure why there is inconsistent behavior.. sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't..